# twitter bootstrap button drop down does not work after all the options are clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, navigation

Once all the options are clicked, the navigation stops working and all the options retain their on hover background color.

This is my html :-

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-large">Action</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">4</div>
</div>
```

and this is the js :-

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
    });

    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `active` options remain active, so you need to clear them out. You can do it like this:-

```
 $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
      $(this).tab('show');
      $('.dropdown-menu > li.active').not($(this).closest('li')).removeClass('active');
  });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JpdRF/)

Changing the text of the button is not a default behavior, as it is not a select deropdown instead it a widget. So you may try this.

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
      $(this).tab('show');
      $('.dropdown-menu > li.active').removeClass('active');
       $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.action').text($(this).text());

  });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fVCWd/)

Comment: this works but this does not change :- <button class="btn btn-large">Action</button>. It remains active throughout

Comment: @StacyJ I don't see this remained active in this example at-least. Could you elaborate or replicate in the fiddle.

Comment: I mean the tab content changes but the button itself remains the same i.e Active

Comment: @StacyJ Did you mean the buttons inthe Menu? That can be resolved by this http://jsfiddle.net/9k8Ar/

Comment: I mean the value of the button remains "Active". It does not change to Home, Profile oe Settings

Comment: @StacyJ Ok that way.. You need to handle it manually default behavior does not support it. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PKevA/